# Do the governments of United Kingdom and USA share immigration data?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, visa-refusals

My brother applied for a US visa in 2008 with a fake document and it was refused on those grounds. In 2015, he got the visas of and traveled to two Schengen countries on another passport. He intends to travel to the UK later this year for a week-long conference. Will the previous US visa refusal be an issue since his biometrics were taken then and does he need to declare these in his UK visa application?

Comment: Yes, they share information. But this is the wrong question. Your brother needs to ask instead, how to get a UK visa anyway, in spite of this incident.

Comment: May I know what was the result of his application? I was also one rejected for US visa but due to not having tie to my home country. I wonder if this may effect my UK visa application. should I mention this in my application?

Comment: @user2807327 Answer all questions truthfully. If you answer truthfully, the very worst that can happen is rejection of this application. If you have fixed the original problem, if you now do have strong enough ties home, it may make no difference at all. If you lie, you are likely to get a 10 year ban. See [What can I do to lift a 10 year ban for making a mistake in my UK visa application?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/64097/19560)

Answer (score 19):

Yes, they share information.  The controlling reference for this is a treaty between the US and UK which was drafted in 2013 and entered into force last year (2014) which says in part...

> CONSIDERING that the effective administration and enforcement of the
>   immigration and nationality laws of the United States of America and
>   the United Kingdom are important to protect the health and safety of
>   their populations, to maintain the security of their societies, and to
>   promote international justice and security by denying access to their
>   territories to persons who are criminals or security risks;
>
> ACKNOWLEDGING that identification of individuals who are inadmissible
>   under their respective immigration laws enhances their ability to
>   facilitate the travel of bona fide visitors;

Source: [Agreement between the Government of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and the Government of the United States of America for the Sharing of Visa, Immigration, and Nationality Information](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/282580/8790.pdf)

So the answer is yes, the two governments share information, not only by this treaty (and similar ones), but also by terms implicit in the "[Special Relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Relationship)".

The shared data includes biometrics.

Similar question, but framed as 'visa-on-arrival' rather than 'visa-application': [Slightly illicit: felon traveling on a US passport; will I be refused entry to the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50904/slightly-illicit-felon-traveling-on-a-us-passport-will-i-be-refused-entry-to-t)

Based upon all of this, it is natural to conclude that a pejorative history in one of the signatories will affect visa decisions in the other signatory.  This does not mean visa applications will be automatically refused, the decision-maker in each country will decide based upon all available information and sometimes this can be favourable to the applicant; but most of the time it would not be favourable to the applicant.

Comment: The UK and USA share immigration information solely based on biometrics. Fingerprints from the UK will anonymously be sent to the USA to check if the applicant has had an encounter with the immigration authorities there. If the fingerprints match, biographic and other details of applications submitted will be shared. Since the USA has the OP's fingerprints on their immigration database, it is safe to assume his visa refusal and the lifetime inadmissibility for material willful misrepresentation will be shared. The OP should continue to travel the non FCC countries. They won't know.

Answer (score 2):

If you take sharing to mean the UK hands over all the data to the US and the UK gets some data on request -- then yes they share.

Comment: Do you have any references to back that up ? It would make for a better answer