# Will removal from UK for overstaying have any impact on US business Visa application?

Tags: legal

I am an Indian citizen,I had been removed from UK on 2011 for overstaying on my Visa. will that performance history have any impact if I apply for US business from the company I am working now.Please advise

Comment: Do you have an explanation about your overstay? How long was it? Were you removed at public expense? Have you travelled internationally since your removal?  It's a great question but lacks vital information. Please edit your question to fill in the missing information, especially your explanation. Thanks.  https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/93294/edit

Comment: You'll want to read this also with a view towards any questions you have https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56986/do-the-governments-of-united-kingdom-and-usa-share-immigration-data/56988#56988

Comment: " apply for US business from the company" you can't apply for a business visa from a company, this makes no sense, please clarify your intent.

Comment: Clarify what visa type you are applying for, bearing in mind the visa type will ultimately have limited impact on the ultimate answer.

Comment: Chances are they won't even ask.