# Deported from UK but got a fresh clean passport. Will the US know?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, passports, deportation

My brother who is from Bangladesh got deported from the UK back in 2009 for working illegally while being a student. His old passport was not machine readable.

Since then he has obtained a new clean machine-readable passport (no record of previous visas) and visited countries like Thailand, Singapore, India, Malaysia. He is now planning to visit the US to attend my college graduation.

If he checks the box to say that he was never deported from any countries, is there any way they can find out about this?

Comment: It is usually safe to assume that Uncle Sam knows everything, such an attempt may backfire

Comment: Passport being machine readable or not does not matter a dime to this situation. They keep the deportation records with themselves primarily, a stamp on passport is just a backup

Comment: One actual immigration violation and one intended immigration violation - is your brother ever intending on being honest...?

Comment: The USA visa process doesn't care if you have been deported from other countries.

Comment: @greatone but it cares a great deal if you lie on your visa application.

Comment: Lying to US immigration is a bad,bad,BAD idea. What you can do is just to request a VISA without lying on the application form and see if they simply accept/deny or call you for clarification.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56986/do-the-governments-of-united-kingdom-and-usa-share-immigration-data Read here and be beware of falsifying facts on the visa application.

Comment: Always be honest with immigration, ends up coming back to bite you!

Comment: @HankyPanky I always assumed it's for less-developed countries who don't have exhaustive computer resources, not for back-up purposes.

Comment: This might have worked in the 1960s. Safe to assume the passport is not the only record in 2017.

Comment: _is there any way they can find out about this?_ Given the amount of information you provided in the question, they can now!

Comment: @Harper Let me reword: The USA visa application does not ask if you have ever been deported from another country.

Comment: @greatone oh!  I see what you mean.  But there's always the chance of an officer asking on arrival.

Comment: The US monitors social media for information. https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/01/british_tourist.html You can bet they monitor this place too. They have tools that aggregate all the posts of people who say that they're about to go to the US. So yes, they know. You just told them, under your real full name too. Not only your brother will be barred, but if you have any other brother, they'll probably be barred too.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In general, the UK and the US partner closely and it's highly likely that **the US will be aware of the UK deportation**.  If your brother claims he has not been deported, but the US has evidence that he was, **the visa will be rejected** for lying on the application and it will be very difficult to *ever* visit the US.

I would advise that he disclose the deportation (if asked) and provide strong evidence that he can afford the trip and intends to return to Bangladesh.  Even if he doesn't get the visa now, at least he will be able to apply again in the future.

Comment: yes. UK and US cooperate very closely on immigration. When I had my passport stolen I had to get a witness who was either British or American (maybe one or two others e.g. Canadian). If one knows something the other does do is a safe bet.

Comment: Not just intent to return to Bangladesh, but means to support himself in the US without working until then. Remember the original problem was working on a student visa.

Comment: And if they *ever* link this question to the brother (not outside the realms of possibility) then he can kiss goodbye to most visas for a loooong time.

Comment: Suggested revision: "I would advise that he disclose the deportation *if asked* . . .". Don't volunteer detrimental information unprompted.

Comment: @Novelocrat Surely there's no way he *won't* be asked? It seems like asking about visa denials, deportations, etc. (even from other countries) would be a standard question on a visa application.

Comment: The question anticipates that there is (or will be) a specific box to check or not check. If that box doesn't exist then the question is moot: if it does exist then the brother has been (or will be) asked :-)

Comment: It also anticipates that if such a box exists, it will ask "Have you ever been deported from *any country*?"  and not "Have you ever been deported from *the United States*?"

Comment: @Novelocrat Visa applications ask about whether you have broken the terms of any visa anywhere. In particular, a first-time visitor to a country cannot possibly have broken any visa terms in that country, and it would be crazy if that led to an automatic assumption that the person is trustworthy. Knowing that somebody had been deported from a country for working illegally would be hugely relevant to any country considering giving that person a visa in the future.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, Despite that I don't think the US DS-160 visa application form asks that question, or much of anything related to non-US travel. This is not to suggest they definitely won't be aware of a UK violation (and if it comes up at the interview lying directly to an officer is treated much more seriously than lying on a form) but the application itself doesn't ask.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, you're right about the DS-160, and the ESTA application form also seems not to ask. Perhaps I was thinking of the [UK visitor visa application form](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589170/VAF1-visitandshorttermstay.pdf), which asks if you've ever been denied a visa, deported or otherwise removed from any country, including the UK (questions 6.3 and 6.6). But, as a UK citizen, I've never interacted with that form.

Comment: @Moo If this is the case, it would be very bad: what if the OP asked the question on his own without consent from the frother? Then it would backfire to the brother without him having caused that.

Comment: @glglgl I think what is backfiring on the brother is him getting himself deported. The brother definitely caused that...

Answer (score 12):

The [DS-160 form](https://www.immihelp.com/visas/sample-ds-160-form-us-visa-application.pdf) which is used for B1/B2 visa applications never actually asks you about deportations or removals from countries other than the US. Therefore your brother would only have to disclose his former transgression if asked so directly during the visa interview. The likelihood of that happening is impossible to estimate accurately, but should that happen the best strategy is to tell the truth. I would also recommend bringing in any documentation related to the deportation from the UK to the visa interview. If the matter comes up you can pull it out and show it. If it doesn't, even better.

As for whether or not the US knows by default... nobody really knows. While there are in fact numerous data sharing agreements between the [Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) countries, there are little details available about how their databases are synchronized and to what extent. Your brother's former history might show up automatically or it might not. The best strategy is to assume it does show up and be 100% open if they ever question this issue.

Comment: There is plenty of information of what is shared/planned to be shared. The USA and Canada share biographic information for immigration purposes when there is derogatory information about an applicant. The rest of the sharing agreements (among the FCC) involve biometrics (currently fingerprints). Unless there is a fingerprint match (which is shared anonymously), no immigration data will be shared. It is safe to assume that unless someone has submitted their fingerprints, chances of the USA finding out about someone's UK immigration history is slim.

Answer (score 1):

Given the country of origin of the visa applicant you will be highly scrutinized and the applicant record double-checked to verify that the claims are true, sorry but at these times being a citizen from certain countries implies a further degree of investigation. Your plan has a high risk of failure. Present all the facts and try to present a strong case that you do not intend to stay or work in the US. Also, request a very short term visa.