# applying for UK visa after attempting an overstay in the united states

Tags: visas, usa, uk

I've been to the united states for 3 months and made an overstay for 1 month. 
and now i want to apply for a uk visa, but I've heard about sharing info between countries ? would that affect me in the future, or it's easy to renew my passport and dont mention my previous us trip ?

Comment: If they find out you risk a ban. They do share information based on fingerprints but not always. Changing passport will not help.

Comment: The US and the UK do share info. See the second answer on this Stack Exchange page: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56986/do-the-governments-of-united-kingdom-and-usa-share-immigration-data#56988

Comment: @DJClayworth Shouldn't your comment's first clause be "The UK is not going to ban you for overstaying in the US" ?

Comment: @David Yes, it should. But it's no longer applicable now anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The UK and USA do share information [Do the governments of United Kingdom and USA share immigration data?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56986/do-the-governments-of-united-kingdom-and-usa-share-immigration-data#56988) You will have to declare the overstay in your UK visa application or you risk an automatic refusal under Paragraph 320(7A) of the Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal if they find out about it, and a 10 year ban for deception.

Comment: what about applying for a schengen visa?

Comment: The visa application form only asks for the purpose of visit and length of stay for previous travel. The OP doesn't really have to mention whether or not that stay was legal. Better yet, the form asks for only the last 2 visits to any Western country for the last 10 years. It would be better to leave the overstay bit for the UK to find out if they're not specifically asking for it anywhere. No need to volunteer information not required.

Comment: The UK visit visa application asks for number of visits, reason, date of visit and length of stay in the past 10 years specifically for Australia, Canada, New Zealand, USA and Schengen, and for any other countries. If the OP entered the US visa-free that information plus their nationality would likely reveal an overstay, given the typical maximum is 90 days; if they entered on a visa it may also be obvious to the ECO, even without information-sharing.