# DS-160 Immigration Law Violation Information for UK Banned Person

Tags: visas, usa, uk, visa-bans

I work for a global company and need to travel to US with a B1/B2 visa; however, I do not actually know what to answer for below question:

> "Have you ever sought to obtain or assist others to obtain a visa,
>   entry into the United States, or any other United States immigration
>   benefit by fraud or willful misrepresentation or other unlawful
>   means?"

In 2009, I was refused and banned by UK for future applications for 10 years since they did not find my language requirement document genuine.

Does that mean I should answer YES to that question? I sought advice from my company's own visa department, and they told me that the question is only for United States applications and thus need to be answered as "No".

I would gladly answer “Yes” and explain my situation rather than misrepresent myself, but would like to get your advice about the situation as well as I am not comfortable giving unnecessary details if it is not mandatory.

Update: As of late 2019, I succesfully been granted a visa to US for my business travel. Answered the question "No" like suggested here if anyone's wondering. Please note that application been done after my ban for UK expired, though I am not sure if it is effected anything at all.

Comment: The usual advice is that you should answer every question as accurately as you can, without lying, even by omission, but without volunteering information that was not requested. Since they ask about US immigration, tell them about any problems you have had with US immigration and nothing else.

Comment: As others have said, the question relates to the US. But you should be aware that the UK and the US share immigration data https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56986/do-the-governments-of-united-kingdom-and-usa-share-immigration-data

Comment: Given the likelihood that the US will know about the ban, and the reason for the ban, it is even more important than usual to make sure every document is undeniably valid.

Comment: Thank you Patricia and Traveller. Unfortunately, I cannot change the past and 100% aware that the US will likely know about the ban. As a first step, I just wanted to make sure that I answer every question correctly. Each document will of course be exact and genuine with my company’s visa letter, their funding for my travel, meeting request from US based company, reservations, degrees etc. If it ever comes to a point that they want me to explain what happened, I will happily explain as well as I was just an unaware student 10 years ago and everything’s totally different in the present day. :)

Comment: @David on the other hand, since Ozzy's answer is correct, it would be more courteous to accept it.  One could also post one's own answer to add details if necessary, or perhaps post a comment on Ozzy's answer.  I agree that editing the answer into the text of the question is usually not the best approach.

Comment: I don't disagree, @phoog. Ozzy did answer the question asked. The OP offered additional info that, I thought, properly belonged in an Answer and not wihtin the question.

Comment: @phoog and David, thanks for the heads up. I never thought that editing the question would result to such an understanding. Thanked Ozzy and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the wording is as you've stated, then it just refers to entries into the US and you may safely put "No".

> "Have you ever sought to obtain or assist others **to obtain a visa, entry into the United States**, or any other **United States immigration benefit** by fraud or willful misrepresentation or other unlawful means?"

Comment: As of late 2019, I succesfully been granted a visa to US for my business travel. Answered the question "No" like suggested here if anyone's wondering. Please note that application been done after my ban for UK expired, though I am not sure if it is effected anything at all. Thanks for the help Ozzy and everyone.