# UK visa in the USA , Biometrics data retained by US?

Tags: visas, uk

For those people who went through the process of UK visa in the United States , my question is that does the USCIS get to keep a copy of your UK visa application ? Because on the GOV UK website it says that "you should bring the application print-out" . I just want to know if the USCIS (a United States Government agancy) will get to keep a copy your UK visa application ? I would appreciate it if you don't just copy and paste info from the GOV UK website and respond only if you went through the process . Thank you in advance

Comment: You might review this question and its answers: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56986/do-the-governments-of-united-kingdom-and-usa-share-immigration-data